# Dealing with unformatted data array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using a function which is returning me some data like this :

```
[{url1: "number1"},{url2: "number2"},{url3: "number3"},etc...]
```

Here is the function, which I didn't write myself :

```
const getNbShares = function() {
    return Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)
                  .map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
                    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
                    const share = $('.nb-shares').html();
                    let shareTuple = {};
                    shareTuple[urls[index]] = share;
                    return shareTuple;
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite this function so I have a proper array object (the best solution but more complicated ?) or is there a way to reformat the data array I have above so I can have something like this :

```
[{url:"url1",value: "number1"},{url:"url2",value: "number2"},{url: "url3", value: "number3"},etc...]
```

Comment: Suggest adding language tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just change the keys:

```
const getNbShares = function() {
    return Promise.map(urls, requestPromise)
                  .map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
                    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
                    const share = $('.nb-shares').html();
                    let shareTuple = {};

                    // set `url` to `urls[index]`
                    shareTuple.url = urls[index];

                    // then set the `value` to `share`
                    shareTuple.value = share;

                    return shareTuple;
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('We encountered an error' + e));
}
```

Comment: Ok. It's working perfectly. I think I really don't understand what's this line of code doing `shareTuple[urls[index]]`... It's looks like some kind of Python to me.

Comment: No it's not Python. It's ES6 (JavaScript). It's just accessing object properties.